# MongoDB Updating a question title - stuck

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to update the title of my question with mongoose. I built my model and I wrote my route but there is something wrong in my syntax I guess since my request failed to update the title of my question.
I will appreciate your comments. All the best,

here is my piece of code:

```
router.post("/update-titlequestion", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const formId = req.fields.formId;

    if (formId) {
      const form = await Form.findByIdAndUpdate(formId);


      form.questions.title = req.fields.title;


      await form.save();


      return res.json(form);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Form not found" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

My mongoose model is the following:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Form = mongoose.model("Form", {
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  questions: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
      },

      answers: {
        type: Array,
      },
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Form;
```

Comment: According to your `Schema`, the `questions` is of type `Array`.  Title of which question from the array are you planning to update

Comment: @Vishnu thanks for your message, I would like to update the title of the questions included in an array. Basically, I have a form composed by an array of questions Each question is composed by an array of answers. My goal is to update the title of each question of my form

Comment: Okay, let's say you have 5 objects in the `questions` array. So are you planning to update the title of all 5

Comment: I fixed my issue with a map function. thanks a lot for your support